# how to make a widget to be on the bottom of the screen if using SliverStack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

[image]

as you can see at the image above, I have a red container stick on the top (right below the app bar). here is the code I use

```
  CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(),
          _buildStack(),
      ]
  ),

 
  
  Widget _buildStack() {
    return SliverStack(
       children: [

        // I have other widgets here ..

        SliverPositioned(
          bottom: 0, // <-- I have set the bottom to be zero
          child: SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: _buildRedBox(),
        ),
     
     ],
   )
 }
  

  Widget _buildRedBox() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.red,
    );
  }
```

I am using [sliver tool package](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) so I can access `SliverStack` and `SliverPositioned`.

as you can see, I have set the bottom to be zero. but the red box is still on the top. I need to make the red box at the bottom of the screen inside my SliverStack. how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SliverFillRemaining widget instead of SliverPositioned widget.

SliverFillRemaining will automatically size itself to fill the space between the bottom of the last list item and the bottom of the viewport

```
SliverFillRemaining(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          _buildRedBox(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```